# MailChimp API V3 Creating Interest (group)

Tags: php, mailchimp, endpoint

I have a web app written in PHP that uses Mailchimp API v3. It was working ok until two days ago. I can't figure out what is going on. When I try to create new interest, I get 500 error, so in my response I don't get interest ID which I use later on. However, the interest gets created, which is weird.

I use the correct ENDPOINT. It's the same one shown in the API Playground. Even when I try to do this in the PLAYGROUND, I get the same error, but the interest (group) gets created.

Endopoint:

```
"http://".$dc.".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/".$list_id."/interest-categories/".$subgroup_id."/interests"
```

Comment: 500 means an error on MailChimp's side; what did their customer support team say about it?

Comment: Still waiting for them to respond.

Comment: Mailchimp API Support said that they have been seeing that when making a POST call to the endpoint /lists/{list_id}/interest-categories/{interest_category_id}/interests that this has resulted in a 500 error. Now we wait for their developers to fix it.